# How send more than 1 image from my views.py function to my template?

Tags: python, django, io, django-views, django-templates

In my views.py, i create 2 subplot and send the plot(of these 2 subplot) to my template in order to display it. 
I would like to send my 2 subgraphs separately to my template in order to display them in different places in my templates, but I can't do it. 
here my views.py:

```
def Cdr3Results(request):
  t1 = np.arange(0.0, 5.0, 0.1)
  t2 = np.arange(0.0, 5.0, 0.02)

  plt.subplot(211)
  plt.plot(t1, np.exp(-t1) * np.cos(2 * np.pi * t1), "bo")
  plt.plot(t2, np.exp(-t2) * np.cos(2 * np.pi * t2), "k")

  plt.subplot(212)
  plt.plot(t2, np.cos(2 * np.pi * t2), "r--")

  fig = plt.gcf()
  buf = io.BytesIO()
  fig.savefig(buf, format='PNG', bbox_inches='tight')
  buf.seek(0)
  string = base64.b64encode(buf.read())
  uri = parse.quote(string)
  return render(request, 'data/cdr3Results.html', {'data': uri})
```

here is how i display the plot of these 2 subpot in my template file:

```
<img src = "data:image/png;base64,{{ data }}" alt="" height="500" width="600">
```

and here the 2 plots: [picture of the plots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUuLO.jpg)

All that i need is to send these 2 plot in 2 differents object of my dictionnary that i send to my template. Could someone please help me please, i have been trying for several days.

Comment: ```return render(request, 'url', {'data1': plot1, 'data2': plot2}``` Did you mean this?

Comment: hello, for your answer that you gave me the other day I think there was confusion, it was not exactly what I was looking for. What I wanted to know is how to send 2 different figures (from plot1 <- plt.fig () and plot2 <- plt.fig ()) from my view to my template? In your last answer, you added 'data2': plot2 in the dictionary and that's what I wanted to do, but what I wanted to know is how to create plot2 in a way that I can send with plot1 in my template?

Comment: As you can see in the code (of views.py) that I provided, I managed to send a plot after putting it in a buffer then translated into string (in the variable "uri") in order to send it to my template. But what I can't do is transform a second plot (which I also get from plt.gcf ()) in the same way so that I can send it to my template at the same time ...